# How can I create my event in OctoberCMS plugin and fire it in the controller?

Tags: laravel, events, octobercms

I trying to fire an event after a question is voted on in the forum to notify the question author about the new development. The CMS documentation is very clear about listening to events but not about creating the event themselves. So I created the event the laravel way as follows:

**author/myplugin/classess/events/QuestionVotedEvent.php**

```
<?php namespace Author\Myplugin\Classes\Events;

use Illuminate\Broadcasting\Channel;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;
use Illuminate\Broadcasting\PrivateChannel;
use Illuminate\Broadcasting\PresenceChannel;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Events\Dispatchable;
use Illuminate\Broadcasting\InteractsWithSockets;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Broadcasting\ShouldBroadcast;

class QuestionVotedEvent
{
    use Dispatchable, InteractsWithSockets, SerializesModels;

    /**
     * Create a new event instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */

    public $question;
    public $voter;
    public $vote;
    public $url;


    public function __construct($question,$voter,$vote,$url)
    {
        $this->question = $question;
        $this->voter = $voter;
        $this->vote = $vote;
        $this->url = $url;

    }

    /**
     * Get the channels the event should broadcast on.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Broadcasting\Channel|array
     */
    public function broadcastOn()
    {
        return new PrivateChannel('channel-name');
    }
}
```

Then in boot() method inside **myplugin**

```
Event::listen('author.myplugin.QuestionVoteEvent', function($question,$vote,$voter) {

    $author = Question::where('id',$question)->first();
    if(!$author)
    {
        return false;
    }
    //Check if the is an upvote and award rps to the author of the question
    if($vote==1)
    {
        //Get rps type
        $rpsType = RPSType::where('code','UV')->first();
        $rps = new RPS;
        $rps->from_user_id = $voter;
        $rps->to_user_id = $author->user_id;
        $rps->rps_type_id = $rpsType->id;
        $rps->rps = $rpsType->points;
        $rps->url = $url;
        $rps->save();
        //Next send notfication to the user 
        //mailing logicgoes here...

    }




});

    }
```

**In my controller**
Event::fire(new QuestionVotedEvent($question,$vote,$voter,$url));

The listner is not passing data into the database table as expected. The thing is the handler is not handling the event.
I have also tried this in the listener **$event->question** to pass the data from the event container to the handler without success.

My problem seem to be at the listener. I seem not be getting it right when trying to listen to my event. How would resolve this? Is this the right way or you would suggest a better way, I will appreciate thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure you didn't find this portion, its pretty easy to fire and listen events.

actually you don't need to create events you just `listen for them` and `fire at some point` [it will work if you don't have any complex work flow]

let me convert your code to..  like that

> Create an event in-short listening for event  
>   you need to write this code **inside your plugin's** `Plugin.php` **file's** `boot` method

```
use Event;  // add this to top if needed 

class Plugin extends PluginBase
{
    [...]

    public function boot()
    {
        Event::listen('author.myplugin.QuestionVoteEvent', function ( 
           $question,
           $vote,
           $voter,
           $url
        ) {
            // your code 
            // [$question, $vote, $voter, $url] all 4 variable will be available here.
        }
    }
}
```

> Now inside controller fire it directly

```
use Event; // add this to top if needed 


// from action fire event
Event::fire('author.myplugin.QuestionVoteEvent', [$question, $vote, $voter, $url]);

// note: this all 4 variables [$question, $vote, $voter, $url] will be passed
// to that event listener function as arguments and you can receive data there
```

for more reference you can use this link : https://octobercms.com/docs/services/events

if getting any issue please comment.

Comment: There was something I was actually misunderstanding. This was creating a separate even container. I dint knew values are bind to the listener automatically. Thanks very much. You saved my day.